# Can't see ViewModel classes in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I want to start using MVVM in a Kotlin project.

In the `build.gradle` of the app module I have:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.0"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"
```

In the `build.gradle` of the project I have:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
    google()
}
```

Then I have:

```
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
        private val view: MainActivityView
) : android.arch.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModel {
```

but ViewModel is not recognized as a symbol

I have also tried:
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0"

and it did not work either.

What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following dependencies and it should work:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"
```

If you want to use these from another module in your project, then use `api` instead of `implementation`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this as dependency also

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0"
```